# Dynamic Spinner for android studios

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-spinner

Ok I am creating an android project that will use 2 spinners. The first one is set from an stable array list of states. The second one will give a list of schools in that state. The list of schools is stored in a SQL database and is added to by users. So once I pass the state value I can get the school list. The only thing Is I cant seem to avoid the null pointer from the schoolList. here is the code for the page. Any ideas would be helpful.

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener {

Button bCancel, bRegister;
EditText etEmail, etPassword, etUserName;
Spinner stateList, schoolList;

//Scope variables strings
String uName=null,email=null,pass=null,school=null,state=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


    bCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
    bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    stateList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.stateList);
    schoolList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.schoolList);

    setState();
    ArrayList<Object> defAda= new ArrayList<>();
    defAda.add("Select State First");
    ArrayAdapter schoollist = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, defAda);
    schoolList.setAdapter(schoollist);
    schoolList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
}

    );

    stateList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            stateList = (Spinner)parent;
            state=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if (state !=null) {
                setSchool(state);
                schoolList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        schoolList = (Spinner) parent;
                        school = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    bCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void setState(){
    ArrayList<String> states=CCValueStore.getStatesList();
    ArrayAdapter stateslist = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
    stateList.setAdapter(stateslist);
}

public void setSchool(String state){
    ArrayList<Object> schools;
    ServerRequests getSchool;
    getSchool = new ServerRequests(this);
    schools=getSchool.getSchoolUserBackground(state, new GotSchoolCallBacks() {

                @Override
                public ArrayList done(ArrayList<Object> returnedSchools) {
                    return returnedSchools;
                }
            });
    schools.add("Not Selected");
    ArrayAdapter schoollist = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, schools);
    schoolList.setAdapter(schoollist);
}
@Override
public void onStart(){

    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.bCancel) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, logIn.class));

    }
    if (v.getId() == R.id.bRegister) {
        uName = etUserName.getText().toString();
        pass = etPassword.getText().toString();
        email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        state = stateList.getSelectedItem().toString();
        school = schoolList.getSelectedItem().toString();

        CCuser UserData = new CCuser(uName, pass, email, state, school);
        boolean success = registerUser(UserData);
        if (success) {
            ServerRequests registered;
            registered = new ServerRequests(this);
            registered.storeUserDataBackground(UserData, new StoreUser() {
                @Override
                public void done(boolean isOk) {

                }
            });
            startActivity(new Intent(this, logIn.class));
        }
    }
}

public boolean registerUser(final CCuser userData) {
    boolean forward= Boolean.parseBoolean(null);
    final String[] chkE = new String[1]; final String[] chkN = new String[1];
    final ServerRequests chkUser = new ServerRequests(this);
    chkUser.fetchUserDataByName(userData, new CheckUserName() {

        @Override
        public void done(CCuser returnedUser) {
            chkN[0] = returnedUser.uName;

        }

    });
    chkUser.fetchUserDataByEmail(userData, new CheckUserEmail() {
        @Override
        public void done(CCuser returnedUser) {
            chkE[0] =returnedUser.email;

        }
    });
    if (chkN[0].equals(userData.uName))
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder notFound = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
        notFound.setMessage("User Name already exists");
        notFound.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        notFound.show();
        forward=false;
    }
    else if (chkE[0].equals(userData.email)){
        AlertDialog.Builder notFound = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
        notFound.setMessage("That email is already assigned to a user");
        notFound.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        notFound.show();
        forward = false;
    }
    else if (chkN[0].equals("") && chkE[0].equals("")) {
        forward = true;
    }
    return forward;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont try to load the data into a Map that has the states as a Key and the List of the Corresponding schools as the Entry for that key and then from the `statesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()` load the right schools into new List and Send it to the SchoolsSpinnerAdapter .

i hope this will help you :)

Comment: please forgive me I am new to using jbdc. At the same time i have only used maps to send data via http from strings where i knew the exact data. So what you are suggesting is generating a map where the key is repeated several times, gathering those repeats into one map array then returning that array based off the key.

Comment: I also believe that will still leave me with the null pointer that I have now, reason being is that the second spinner is still waiting for an value to gather array for the second spinner.

Comment: there is something not stopping the call to set schools. It is generating that  command premature. I have even tried making the arraylist global (to the scope ) then running the this check if(states.contains(state)) { setSchools();}  for some reason it's getting schools no matter what I try. So if this helps anyone else see my issue. please let me know

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem to this was in something I didn't post. Building the app around a web interface I created an auth key. I named the key auth in the app and was looking for an appAuth for retrieval to gain access to my web server. Hence the null pointers. I was getting the errors on school only because that was the first call to the web. Once I aligned the values being sent with the values being retrieved things went smoothly.

I also took another approach and created a list view instead of a spinner and used fragmented data being other parts of the application will also use the same methods.